# How to convert a Java object to key-value pair without using reflection

Tags: java, gwt

Is it possible to convert a plain Java `Object` with the usual `getXXX` and `setXXX` methods for its fields to a key-value pair, like `Map<String, Object>`?

I need to to  this without relying on Java reflection, so it can be used with a Java-To-Javascript compiler like GWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before by using a MapSerialisation interface:

```
interface MapSerialisation {
    Map<String, Object> toMap();
    void fromMap(Map<String, Object>);
}
```

Implement that on each of your model objects and use that for translation.

Another method I've used is Google Collections' Transformers, and having model transformation functions to convert between a Java object and a structure that Javascript would like.

I'd probably be tempted to use Jackson to serialise into JSON though.

Answer (score 3):

GWT comes with a mechanism called [Deferred Binding](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html) as a replacement for reflection. While normally you only use this API by calling `GWT.create(Class<?>)`, it can also be used to write code generators that are invoked during the GWT compile process (i.e. the Java-to-Javascript translation).

You could use this to create a code generator that will output for any of your POJO classes
a helper class which would contain the `toMap()` and `fromMap()` methods. GWT offers an API that is kind of similar to Java's reflection API with classes like `JClassType`, `JMethod`, etc. These can be used to query classes (that you want to generate code for) for their getters and setters and generate the above-mentioned methods accordingly.

Your client code would then basically look like this:

```
Pojo1 pojo1 = ...;
// Pojo1Transformer is the class that is generated for your domain class Pojo1
Pojo1Transformer pojo1Transformer = GWT.create(Pojo1Transformer.class);
Map<String, Object> pojo1AsMap = pojo1Transformer.toMap(pojo1);
...
pojo1AsMap.put(Pojo1Transformer.NAME, "New Name");
Pojo1 changed = pojo1Transformer.fromMap(pojo1AsMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is the most logical way to do this, some might argue that Class GetMethods / Fields are not technically reflection altogether.

One way to do this is to implement toHash() function where you could explicitly create a Hashtable / Map of your Object.